# Host WCF in IIS 7 using net.tcp binding

Tags: wcf, iis-7, net.tcp

I am hosting a WCF service in IIS 7 through net.tcp binding. I have two questions about IIS configuration.

1. Can I only configure net.tcp protocol in the the web site containing my service code? All the samples I found so far always append the net.tcp protocol after http protocol.
2. There are two features we can turn on: Windows Communication Foundation Http Activation and Windows Communication Foundation Non-Http Activation. Some sample state that we need to turn on Non-Http activation and others state that both are required to turn on. My test shows that both are required. However, I do not understand the difference between the two. If only net.tcp protocol is used by my service and client, why should Http Activation be required?

Answer (score 0):

Even if your service is net.tcp the meta data exchange that is used when you add a service reference may be http.

Which tests did you do? If you need more help post your config file.

Comment: For my case, the service is used internally and there is no need to expose the meta data. I do not understand why Microsoft makes the http binding compulsory when it is not used. For the http activation part, I guess I know why. The module helps to register the svc file type to IIS. So even I am using net.tcp, the end point is still a svc file.